# Access javascript strict function

Tags: javascript, function, strict

I am learning about Javascript 'use strict' mode, facing a trivial problem.. kindly correct me, if my understanding is worng.

file1.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

     var testObject = {
            "id" : 1,
            "label" : "Object 1"
        };

     printUserInformation = function (userName){
          console.log(" Test Object is "+testObject + " User is "+ userName );
     }
});
```

file2.js

```
printUserInformation("StackOverflow User");
```

but when i m calling/invoking function from outside strict mode getting undefined error, and unable to access testObject as well. Any Guide will be useful.

Comment: From this jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/w3aay7ju/  I get `ReferenceError: printUserInformation is not defined`.

Comment: So you got a strict function that is not executed that contains a local variable and an implicit global variable.

Comment: `use strict;` must appear at the top of the file isnt it

Comment: @surajck: No, that's not correct.

Comment: So, in the above example, only the code within the function executes in `strict` mode?

Comment: @surajck: It's slightly more complicated than that, but basically, yes.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem has nothing to do with strict mode. Your `printUserInformation` function is scoped only to the anonymous function you've put it in, it's not global, so `file2.js` doesn't have access to it. There are also a couple of other problems: You never call your scoping function, so the code inside it (including the code defining `printUserInformation` is never run), and if it were it would throw a `ReferenceError` because you try to assign to an undeclared variable (`printUserInformation`), which causes an error in strict mode.

If you just want to enable strict mode for `file1.js` without avoiding creating globals, you don't need the scoping function:

```
'use strict';

var testObject = {
       "id" : 1,
       "label" : "Object 1"
};

var printUserInformation = function (userName){
      console.log(" Test Object is "+testObject + " User is "+ userName );
};
```

That deals with all three problems. The first two are dealt with by removing the scoping function (that does mean that the code creates two globals, though); the third (the undeclared variable) is fixed by adding `var` in front of the line starting with `printUserInformation = function...`. I also added a `;` at the end of that function expression because you want a `;` at the end of assignment statements.

---

In a comment you've asked:

> can u tell me how can i access with using `(function () { printUserInformation ..... })`

If you want to use a scoping function (which is generally a good idea) but create globals within it, you have a couple of options:

1. Return the thing you want to make public out of the scoping function when you call it
2. Create the global within the scoping function by assigning to a property on the global object

Here's what #1 looks like:

```
var printUserInformation = (function() {
    'use strict';

    var testObject = {
           "id" : 1,
           "label" : "Object 1"
    };

    var printUserInformation = function (userName){
          console.log(" Test Object is "+testObject + " User is "+ userName );
    };

    return printUserInformation;
})();
```

Note that we don't just define the scoping function, but we **call** it (the `()` at the very end), which was missing from the code in the question.

There, `testObject` is still nicely contained (it's not a global), but `printUserInformation` is a global.

I should note that the parens wrapped *around* the function aren't strictly necessary there, but since they'd be necessary if we weren't assigning the result somewhere, people are used to see them. `var x = function() { return 42; }();` *works* (`x` will be `42`), but is likely to throw people.

Here's one of the many ways #2 looks:

```
(function(global) {
    'use strict';

    var testObject = {
           "id" : 1,
           "label" : "Object 1"
    };

    global.printUserInformation = function (userName){
          console.log(" Test Object is "+testObject + " User is "+ userName );
    };
})(this);
```

At global scope and not in strict mode, `this` refers to the global object. So we pass that reference into the scoping function as an argument, `global`. Strict mode is in force *within* the scoping function, but not outside it.

On browsers, instead of using `this`, you can use `window`, which is a property on the global object (e.g., a global variable) that refers to the global object. So you can do this instead:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var testObject = {
           "id" : 1,
           "label" : "Object 1"
    };

    window.printUserInformation = function (userName){
          console.log(" Test Object is "+testObject + " User is "+ userName );
    };
})();
```

But that's just on browsers, not in other environments (NodeJS, SilkJS, etc.).

Using scoping functions is really handy. In an environment like the browser, where the global namespace is ***really*** crowded, avoiding creating globals is a Good Thing<sup>(tm)</sup>. If you're not using AMD (RequireJS, etc.), it's generally best to create only **one** global, which is an object that you put anything else on. The pattern for that looks like this:

```
// This bit is in each file: It creates the `MyApp` global and
// initializes it with a blank object if it doesn't already exist,
// or just uses the existing MyApp object if it already exists.
var MyApp = window.MyApp || {};

// Then we define this file's contents inside a scoping function
(function() {
    "use strict";

    // ...private stuff here...

    // Let's make one public function
    MyApp.printUserInformation = function() { /* ... */ };
})();
```

(And in a non-browser environment, you can change `window` to `this` in the above.)

Comment: Tried this : http://jsfiddle.net/w3aay7ju/3/ and it works.  So the issue is with scope and not `use strict`

Comment: Thnx a lot , can u tell me how can i access with using (function () { printUserInformation .....  })

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, you are right, it's just my habit to reiterate stuff to make myself understand.  Nothing meant to steal anyone's thunder.

Comment: @DigitalAlchemist: I heard you the first time. :-) I've updated the answer to address that question.